# Check if date exist or not

Tags: python

So i have been tring to make a program about, is that a correct date, but my if statement doesnt seem to work. So this is my whole code

```py
date = int(input("Enter a date: "))
month = int(input("Enter a month[1-12]: "))
year = int(input("Enter a year: "))

if month > 12:
    print("This is an invalid date")
elif month <= 12:
    if month in ('1','3','5','7','8','10','12'):
        if date > 31:
            print("This is an invalid date")
    else:
        print("This is a valid date")
elif month in ('4','6','9','11'):
    if date > 30:
        print("This is an invalid date")
    else:
        print("This is a valid date")
elif month == 2:
    if date <= 28:
        print("This is a valid date")
    elif date == 29:
        if (year%4==0):
            print("This is a valid date")
        else:
            print("This is an invalid date")
```

most of the code seems to work but this part always prints its an invalid date:

```py
if month in ('1','3','5','7','8','10','12'):
    if date > 31:
        print("This is an invalid date")
    else:
        print("This is a valid date")
elif month in ('4','6','9','11'):
    if date > 30:
        print("This is an invalid date")
    else:
        print("This is a valid date")
```

Help woul be really appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: Whatever integer you test, it will never be in those lists of strings.

Comment: tldr convert month to string

Comment: Its going to do that because.  If month <=12 and if month in ('1','3','5','7','8','10','12'): else print(invalid).     If i input 2. First it will check if 2 is <= 12. 2nd check if month in ('1','3','5','7','8','10','12'): so this is false then it's going to print(invalid) since 2 not in list

Comment: It works now. Thabk you everyone for taking your time and helping me

Answer (score 0):

your month and date datatype is int and your program is searching for a string.
so it will never match to the date.

replace int to str in input() and also in month where your condition has int datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You should use datetime module.

```
from datetime import date

# Now yuo can check each value doing this:

if date.max.month >= given_month >= date.min.month:
    # Given month is in range...

if date.max.year >= given_year >= date.min.year:
    # and so on
```

Or checking for an error during the date building:

```
try:
    date(day=given_day, month=given_month, year=given_year)
except ValueError as error_in_date:
    print(error_in_date)
```

More usefull hint are here:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html